# iPhone Google Maps and GPS location

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, qr-code

I have created a QR Code which displays a map of our mountain bike trails. First off I'm not an Apple guy, so I'm not sure what needs to be done to make this cross platform Android and Apple. The QR Code works correctly on Android. When scanned it opens up the kml file in Google Maps and displays the map and your GPS location.

[image: Mountain bike trails qr code map]

When I scan this with an iPhone is displays the map and asks if you would like to accept sharing your current location. I accept it but it won't display my location. Is there something I need to do to make it work on Android and Apple, or any other suggestions. A little frustrating. As I look at the logs majority of the users what scan the code are iphones so I need to get it to work on them.

Update: here is a screenshot of the iPhone.

[image]

It should also have your gps location like this

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you writing an app?

Comment: No, just using google maps to open a kml file. However, I am considering writing an app if opening a kml file doesn't work on Android and Apple.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what happens when you scan the QR?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, the default Google Maps behavior appears to be to show to the current location up front.

On iOS, however, it seems that Google Maps decides that the user can hit the location button if they want thier current location.

As far as I'm concerned, I side with Google.

Also, it could be that you need to try some different QR scanners - some might automatically show the location, some might decide to conserved resources instead.

<sub>P.S. To take a screenshot on iPhone, press the lock and home buttons at the same time :)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot tip. Thought there had to be a way. I feel stupid again when I use an iPhone :) After playing around with a friend's yesterday I know I so prefer Android!